# CakePHP Sub Querys, How To?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, find

I have a post model (mysql table), and the structure is something like:

```
id, parent, user_id, title, desc, created, modified
```

A single thread of conversation consists of a post, followed by all subsequent posts where post.parent matches the original post_id.

Sample Conversation between user_32 and user_40:

```
110, 0, 32, thread_title, sample_description_here, created_time, modified_time
121, 110, 40, comment_title, sample_comment_here, created_time, modified_time
130, 110, 32, comment_title, sample_comment_here, created_time, modified_time
140, 110, 32, comment_title, sample_comment_here, created_time, modified_time
166, 110, 40, comment_title, sample_comment_here, created_time, modified_time
290, 110, 32, comment_title, sample_comment_here, created_time, modified_time
```

With plain PHP I simply do the outer query, followed by the inner query and then echo the conversation to the screen,  but how do you achieve this with CakePHP??

QUESTION:

How do I construct the query in CakePHP, to display a single conversation composed of (see above) post_id_110, followed by all subsequent posts where post.parent == 110, ordered by created_time DESC.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Post model:

> ```
> var $hasMany = array(
>   'Children'=>array(
>     'className' => 'Post',
>     'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
>    )
>  );
> ```

(and change 'parent' to 'parent_id' in DB, just a convention). Then in posts controller:

> ```
> $this->Post->find('first',array(
>    'conditions'=>array(...),
>    'contain'=>array('Children')
> ));
> ```

oh yeah, and use Containable. You don't really need that for the purpose, but it makes the find() clearer and definitely helpful later on.

Comment: Cool, and how do I draw that in the view? I currently have a foreach loop, but it aint working since I made the above changes. Thanks

Comment: just print out the output of that find() to see the result array, and you can loop through that.

Answer (score 1):

in post model:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'ParentPost' => array(
        'className' => 'Post',
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
    ),
)
```

and then use as every other associate model

btw - parent_id is more cakeish than parent and works with scaffolds

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "associate model"?  In my controller I have $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions))  ); So how do I now get the conversation to display?? thanks